# Leibniz rule; Solving differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Could you help me with a question? I get stuck at ii),

Define the function

$$I(x):=\frac{1}{\pi} \int^\pi_0 \cos(x\sin\theta) d\theta$$

i) Via application of Leibniz rule (or otherwise) calculate $I'$ and $I''$.

ii) Thus, determine non-zero value(s) of $k$ for which $I$ will be a solution to the differential equation

$$k^2x^2I''+xI'+x^2I=0$$

iii) Write down the values of $I(0)$ and $I'(0)$.

So far what I have is 
$$I'(x)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int^\pi_0 -\sin\theta \sin(x\sin\theta) d\theta$$
$$I''(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int^\pi_0 -\sin^2\theta \cos(x\sin\theta) d\theta$$

No idea where to go from there :S

Comment: It might be useful for you to note that $I(x) = J_0(x)$ which is the zeroth order Bessel function of the first kind. Also the ODE for $I(x)$ is essentially a Bessel ODE. This might give you some direction and hints at the answers to the problem.

Comment: I haven't learnt about Bessel ODEs or anything like that yet :( Is there anyway I can do it without Bessel ODEs??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to integrate $I^{\prime}(x)$ by parts to get there.
$$\begin{align}I^{\prime}(x)&=\frac1{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\left(\frac d{d\theta}\cos\theta\right)\sin(x\sin\theta)d\theta\\
&=\frac1{\pi}\left[(\cos\theta)\sin(x\sin\theta)\right]_0^{\pi}-\frac1{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\cos\theta\cos(x\sin\theta)\cdot x\cos\theta\,d\theta\\
&=-\frac x{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\cos^2\theta\cos(x\sin\theta)d\theta\end{align}$$
And now you're all set:
$$k^2x^2I^{\prime\prime}+xI^{\prime}+x^2I=\frac{x^2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\left[-k^2\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta+1\right]\cos(x\sin\theta)d\theta=0$$
So we want
$$-k^2\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta+1=(1-k^2)\sin^2\theta=0$$
Thus $k=\pm1$. The last part is straightforward
$$I(0)=\frac1{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}1\cdot d\theta=1$$
$$I^{\prime}(0)=\frac1{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}0\cdot d\theta=0$$

Comment: I think you made a typo when you integrated by parts; you meant to write $\cos(x \sin \theta)$. Also check upper limit on $I'(0)$.

Comment: Yes, and there was a typo on next the two lines which should have been $\cos(x\sin\theta)$ as well. Thanks.